# Calling another function after getting response from API (Axios using vue)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am calling an API with Axios using vue `store` and `mapAction`. I also have one function to call, but only after the API responds. But the function is being called before the API responds.

```js
...mapActions("functionCall", ["functionName"]),
  async refresh() {

    await this.functionName()
    this.test()

  },
  test(){
    console.log('not working well....')
  },
```

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. That you have it suggests that functionName has it, but it wasn't shown

Comment: As long as we don't know what `this.functionName` does and returns it is not possible to say what you do wrong.

Comment: after vuex `functionName()` is being called and immediately the `test()` method is being called too because your function is actually in Vuex and `await` is NOT helping you here. You better await it inside your vuex actions.

Comment: this.functionName() calls a Lambda function and returns the response from there.